# Library to unzip archive in C on osx

Tags: c++, c, macos, zlib

I have been using zlib to inflate some .gz and zip files. The issue is that now I wish to inflate .zip archives but my research and trial and error seems to tell me that zlib cannot do this? If so what other libraries could I used because at the moment I can only find minizip and lzma but both libraries only support Windows.(The best option would be one I can port cross platform).

Thanks
Sam

Comment: zlib is only for *compression*, not for the ZIP archive format. For that do a search for e.g. `libzip` or `libunzip` or similar terms. Or just execute an external command to do the unzipping.

Comment: There is something wrong with your question: you write that you "have been using zlib to **inflate** some .gz and **zip** files" and the the next phrase you write that "zlib cannot **inflate** .zip archives".

Comment: it can inflate single files but not archives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using libzip, and a fantastic example of how to use the library by Mobius https://gist.github.com/mobius/1759816

Answer (score 1):

You can look into POCO libraries. They have support for OS X as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/), which is available both in [MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/archivers/libarchive/Portfile) and [Homebrew](http://brewformulas.org/Libarchive).